# Integrating a SpriteKit view into a xib view

Tags: ios7, xamarin, xib, sprite-kit, skview

I have a view that I already created using a xib file.

Now I would like to add some small elements to this view that would make use some of the physics animations from SpriteKit, so now I need an SKView.

Is it possible to add an SKView as a Subview of the view that corresponds to my xib view? I tried this and it does not seem to show anything.

The following is in the ViewController corresponding to my XIB view:

```
this.myCustomSKView = new CustomSKView()
this.View.AddSubview( this.myCustomSKView );
```

and the ViewController for my custom SKView has:

```
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
        if(this.SKView.Scene == null)
        {
            this.SKView.ShowsFPS = true;
            this.SKView.ShowsNodeCount = true;
            this.SKView.ShowsDrawCount = true;

            var scene = new MyCustomSKScene (this.SKView.Bounds.Size);
            this.SKView.PresentScene (scene);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's possible. Post the code you tried. PS what does that have to do with xamarin?

Comment: I tagged Xamarin because this is the environment I am using.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just skimmed over the code, didn't notice it was C#. I'm blind. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to achieve but I think instead of SpriteKit you may wanna check out the UIKitDynamics which provides "physics-related capabilities and animations to views and other dynamic items". I would suggest you look at the apple doc first
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html
then 
a really nice tutorial on raywenderlich.com
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank-you this is very interesting. I was trying to achieve particles falling at different rates and potentially colliding.

Comment: Don't understand why would anyone downvote this answer! even the author of the accepted answer (Dogcoffee) agrees with me !

Answer (score 4):

I just gave this a try, and worked.

1. Started with single view app.
2. Dragged in myScene.m / .h from another sprite kit app into my project.
3. In storyboard dragged in a UIView, and set class to SKView in storyboard.
4. Created an outlet from that to the VC class (in my case called it myGame)
5. Added the #import  in the VC class
6. Also copied from the demo project viewDidLoad

This is the only change i made

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Next line is all I changed...
   SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
   skView.showsFPS = YES;
   skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

   // Create and configure the scene.
   SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
   scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

   // Present the scene.
   [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

I added in some other UIKit to kind show how its a little SK Game in a view.

[image]

Not sure if this is the best way but I hope I answers your question.

**I agree with lionserdar, and you should check out UIKit Dynamics instead.**

Comment: Thank-you for this sample. I am using Xamarin and I also don't use a storyboard. I simply added an SKView as a Subview to the View that was created from my Xib file. I was trying to achieve particles falling at different rates and potentially colliding.

Comment: Never used Xamarin, if you wanna use xcode, you can port to android using http://www.apportable.com

Comment: How to go back to UIKit screens again