# How can i move to myScene from UIViewController?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I have 2 viewcontroller. In the first viewcontroller, there is the introduction and logo of the game and in the second viewcontroller it loads the skscene. And I travel from my first viewcontroller to second viewcontroller with a button click. But it becones error. My code is in the second viewcontroller is:

```
@interface MPAPViewSceneController()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPAPMyScene *targetScene;
@property SKView *spriteView;
@end



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

 _spriteView = (SKView *)self.view;
 _spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
 _spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
 _spriteView.showsDrawCount   = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  self.targetScene = [[MPAPMyScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(768.0f, 1024.0f)];
 [_spriteView presentScene:self.targetScene];
}

 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
  self.targetScene = nil;
}
```

And in the scene I have written the code given below:

```
@interface MPAPMyScene()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL contentCreated;

@end

@implementation MPAPMyScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
if (self.contentCreated == NO) {
    [self createSceneContents];
    self.contentCreated = YES;
}
}



-(void)willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view {
[self removeAllChildren];
}


-(void)createSceneContents {
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
}
```

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258567/integrating-a-spritekit-view-into-a-xib-view/19266956#19266956

Comment: you neglected to mention what error you're getting

Comment: Thanks Smick. The link answer help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
_spriteView = (SKView *)self.view;
```

to

```
_spriteView = (SKView *)self.targetScene;
```