# sprite kit root view controller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, sprite-kit

How to pop to rootViewController from SKScene?

im trying to build a game with menu screen.
There are two scenes - one for menu and one for game.

I have problem with jumping to rootView from a game scene.
Game scene has SKScene with menu button - SKLabelNode. 
When touched it should move player to menu screen.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    SKNode *touched = [self nodeAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
    if ([touched.name isEqualToString:BUTTON_MENU_NAME]) {

        UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
        [vc.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Touch is detected correctly but nothing happens.

Comment: should be : `appdelegate.window.rootViewController`

Comment: @samfisher still the same - doesnt work

Comment: Set up your project like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258567/integrating-a-spritekit-view-into-a-xib-view/19266956#19266956

Comment: set breakpoint, step through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the initial view controller is the navigation controller so I suggest doing:

```
UINavigationController *vc = (UINavigationController *)appdelegate.window.rootViewController;
[vc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: After hours of pulling my hair out your answer is awesome! I had to change it to this.   UINavigationController *vc = (UINavigationController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
            [vc popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];